# Merge data sets based on two column values

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have looked everywhere and I cannot seem to find a workable solution to this small problem I am having.

I have two large data sets, N=875 and N=922.

`df.1` data set with 875 obs and 27 var
`df.2` data set with 922 obs 23 var

`df.1` has columns `FIRST` and `LAST` which are the first and last names of the individuals, and 25 other columns.

`df.2` has columns `X1` and `X2` which correspond to the first and last names of the individuals, and 21 other columns.

I need to merge `df.1` with `df.2` and throw away any observations that are not in both frames.

So I should now have a data frame with less that 875 observations and 48 columns.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is well documented in [`?merge`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html), which includes a pretty clear example.

Comment: By default `merge` joins by common column names, rename `df2` colnames to match `FIRST` and `LAST` in `df.1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the the variables names are exactly the same for df1 and df2, you could try

```
merge(df1, df2, by = c('X1', 'X2'), all = F)
```

In your case, you will need

```
merge(df.1, df.2, by.x = c('FIRST', 'LAST'), by.y = c('X1', 'X2'))
```

For the data set provided:

```
library(XML)
url1 <- "http://stats.nhlnumbers.com/player_stats/year/2010"
df1 <- readHTMLTable(url1)
names <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df1[[1]][ ,1]),
                                            split = ", ")))
df1 <- cbind(df1, names)
#head(df1)

url2 <- "http://stats.nhlnumbers.com/player_stats/year/2009"
df2 <- readHTMLTable(url2)
names2 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df2[[1]][ ,1]),
                                             split = ", ")))
df2 <- cbind(df2, names2)
#head(df2)

df1_2 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c('X1', 'X2'), all = F)
head(subset(df1_2, select = c('X1', 'X2', 'skaters-data.Name.x',
                              'NULL.PTS/$MM.x', 'NULL.PTS/$MM.y')))
df1_2$Player <- paste(df1_2$X2, df1_2$X1)
url3 <- "http://hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2010_skaters.html"
df3 <- readHTMLTable(url3)
df3 <- as.data.frame(df3)

df4 <- merge(df1_2, df3, by.x = 'Player', by.y = 'stats.Player', all = F)
names(df4) <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "_", names(df4))
head(subset(df4, select = c(X2, X1, Player, NULL_PTS__MM_x,
                            NULL_PTS__MM_y, stats_Rk)))

     X2      X1        Player NULL_PTS__MM_x NULL_PTS__MM_y stats_Rk
1 Aaron Johnson Aaron Johnson         18.519         15.573      344
2 Aaron    Rome    Aaron Rome          7.619          6.698      662
3 Aaron   Voros   Aaron Voros          7.000         16.000      825
4 Aaron    Ward    Aaron Ward          5.200          4.000      834
5  Adam  Burish   Adam Burish          5.614         12.632       95
6  Adam   Foote    Adam Foote          3.000          2.333      228
```

And maybe plot it

```
df5 <- subset(df4, select = c(X2, X1, Player, NULL_PTS__MM_x,
                              NULL_PTS__MM_y, stats_Rk))[1:10, ]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(NULL_PTS__MM_x), y = as.numeric(stats_Rk),
       colour = Player), data = df5) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot it]

Comment: Hey thank you! However, I have been down this road and it seeming not to work. I can get all the variables but no observations, or by using either all.x or all.y I can get all the obersvations but NA's where the variables are in 1 df but not the other. I have been through the help file and I do not understand what is making this so difficult. Can I email my code to anyone so I can get some pointers?

Comment: @KyleBillings could you provide us with some real data?

Comment: 'URL1 <- "http://stats.nhlnumbers.com/player_stats/year/2010"  
     tables.1 = readHTMLTable(URL1) 
     table.1 = tables.1[[2]] 

    URL2 <- "http://stats.nhlnumbers.com/player_stats/year/2009"
    tables.2 = readHTMLTable(URL2) 
    table.2 = tables.2[[1]] 

    URL3 <- "http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2010_skaters.html" 
    tables.3 <- readHTMLTable(URL3) 
    table.3 <- tables.3[[1]] '

Comment: @KyleBillings a txt or csv for df.1 and df.2 would be great!

Comment: The code markup failed me just now. Basically Im pulling NHL Salary data from 2010 and player stats from 2009. There was some minor formatting that had to happen, but then I wanted to combine the two data frames into one. I had no problem merging the nhl numbers data (Table 1 and 2) it is the hockey-refernce data (Table 3) that is giving me the headache

Comment: @KyleBillings. Ok I got it.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `base::merge`, one alternative is using `SQL`.

You can use that in `R` with `sqldf` (but rename your data to `df1` and `df2` without dots `.`)

```
library(sqldf )
sqldf("SELECT *
      FROM df1, df2
      WHERE df1.FIRST==df2.X1
      and df1.LAST == df2.X2")
```

Another alternative is `data.table`, if you have big data sets you should consider this:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key=c("FIRST", "LAST")) #set keys
dt2 <- data.table(df2, key=c("X1", "X2")) #set keys
dt1[dt2] #join
```

---

Starting from `data.table` versions >= 1.9, there's a function `setDT` that converts a `data.frame` (and also a `list`) to `data.table` by reference. That'll make things much more faster and memory efficient (especially in cases where your data is 5GB and you've 8GB RAM). So, it can be done as:

```
require(data.table) # >= 1.9
setDT(df1) # df1 will be a data.table
setDT(df2) # df2 will be a data.table
setkey(df1, FIRST, LAST)
setkey(df2, X1, X2)
df1[df2]
```